# How to fetch only public repositories from my Github account

Tags: graphql, github-api

So I'm completely new to GraphQL, could anyone tell me how to change below code into retrieving only public repos from my account?

I tried to use "search" attribute but I can't get it working.

Thanks

```
  const {
    github: {
      repositoryOwner: {
        repositories: { edges },
      },
    },
  } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
      github {
        repositoryOwner(login: "SzBor") {
          repositories(first: 6, orderBy: { field: CREATED_AT, direction: ASC }) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                name
                url
                description
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
```

Comment: So when you execute this, what's the result? What error do you receive, if any?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the arguments `privacy: PUBLIC`on `repositories` Ex:

```
  const {
    github: {
      repositoryOwner: {
        repositories: { edges },
      },
    },
  } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
      github {
        repositoryOwner(login: "SzBor") {
          repositories(first: 6, privacy: PUBLIC, orderBy: { field: CREATED_AT, direction: ASC }) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                name
                url
                description
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
```

The stranger is that the ([API V4 document](https://developer.github.com/v4/interface/repositoryowner/#fields)) is not updated with this information, but you can test on [explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/) :)